# Show only decimals of float

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

I need to print a `float` showing only the **decimals** of that float. For example:

```
1.23456 --> 23456
12.3456 --> 3456
123.456 --> 456
```

I've found the following solution:

```
float floatValue = 1.23455f;
String stringValue = Float.toString(floatValue);
int pointIndex = stringValue.indexOf(".");
String decimals = stringValue.substring(pointIndex + 1, stringValue.length() - 1);
```

But I think it's a little dirty and I wonder if there is any other standard way, using [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) or something similar. I did't find anything in the documentation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean like `stringValue.split("\\.")[1]` for example?

Comment: You could always separate the fractional part of the float value and format it separately.  But you'll still get the ".", I suspect.

Comment: @HotLicks That could very well give a completely different result - the fractional part of the `float` that represents a certain decimal most accurately may not be the same as the `float` that represents the fractional part of that decimal most accurately; because `float` variables are spaced differently depending on their magnitude.

Comment: In fact I'm looking for a standard way, something like a formatter

Comment: @DavidWallace - Well, the OP hasn't given us the standard "it rounds wrong" gripe yet, but I'm sure it's coming.

Answer (score 1):

```
float floatValue = 1.23455f;
String stringValue = Float.toString(floatValue).split("\\.")[1];
```

Should work for you

Comment: You didn't escape the "." in the pattern.

Comment: damn, this is a regex in java... I am doing too much python atm

Comment: @ZerO Thanks for your answer but I think it is basically the same as mine.

Comment: no it's not. I used split. and you used a substring, which is just not needed

Comment: This gives interesting results if the number is big enough for `Float.toString` to use scientific notation ("capital E" notation).

Comment: @ZerO - Probably substring is better than split, since substring creates only the new String, while split creates 2 Strings and an array.

Comment: but isn't it lost as I do not assign the array to any variable?